# ¿Como puedo integrar una pi key a mi software? en este caso el api de EasyBroker

Tags: api

Pasa que me pidieron integrar una api key, estoy programando en Java, segun por lo que investigue se utiliza algo como HttpsRequest, de ser asi tengo este codigo:

```
String params = "nombre=Juan&edad=5";
        byte[] postData = params.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int postDataLength = postData.length;
        String link = "http://localhost/practicaweb/admin/method/httprequest.php?foo=hoola";
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();
        
        DataOutputStream otw = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        otw.write(postData);
        otw.flush();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        
        StringBuilder dr = new StringBuilder();
        String f;
        while((f=in.readLine())!=null){
            dr.append(f);
        }
        System.out.println(dr);
```

Pero no tengo nada concreto.

Comment: Te recomiendo mucho leas [ask] y de paso hagas el [tour], probablemente tu pregunta quede cerrada

Comment: Gracias por su comentario